# How to allow image pull from one project to another in openshift?

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I have created one project `testing1` in which i published `docker` images.

Now, i want to created similar  another project `testing2` with same images that i pushed in `testing1`. I don’t want to publish it again.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Login to your openshift command line and run command:

```
oc policy add-role-to-user \
    system:image-puller system:serviceaccount:testing2:default \
    --namespace=testing1
```

OR

```
oc policy add-role-to-user \
    system:image-puller system:serviceaccount:testing2:default \
    -n testing1
```

Your project `testing2` will be able to access images from project `testing1` in your openshift.

For more information refer [openshift Documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/dev_guide/image_pull_secrets.html#allowing-pods-to-reference-images-across-projects)

Comment: I *think*, though I'm not 100% sure, that you've got it exactly backwards: `testing1` will be allowed to pull images from `testing2`. After all, you are creating a permission for `testing1` in `testing2`, not vice versa.

Comment: From the docs: `When using the internal registry, to allow pods in project-a (testing1) to reference images in project-b (testing2), a service account in project-a must be bound to the system:image-puller role in project-b`
So you are correct Nikolai, the answer is backwards.  The service account in testing2 needs to be given access to pull from testing1.

Comment: is it possible to allow all projects to pull images from the project testing1 ?