# Openshift: CI/CD access imagestream from different clusters

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, tekton, openshift-pipelines

I'm configuring CI/CD in OpenShift: Dev > Stage > Prod and I'm facing some issues in Stage to reach Dev ImageStream. The whole setup looks like this:

Dev - runs Tekton pipeline and on the last task triggers BuildConfig > Build outputs new image to ImageStream > ImageStream new tag triggers DeploymentConfig > Deployment happens

Stage - I'd like to reach tag in ImageStream in Dev so I could build and deploy application in Stage.

I'm using OpenShift internal registry `image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:port`

In Stage what I've done is one Task in Pipeline to execute `image-pull` command:

```
oc import-image image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:port/namespace/name:version --confirm
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): imagestreams.image.openshift.io "name" is forbidden: 
User "system:serviceaccount:namespace:sa" cannot get resource "imagestreams" in API group "image.openshift.io" in the namespace "namespace"
```

I've a serviceAccount `sa` in Dev and Stage the same which only has github-secret.

According to some examples like [OpenShift documentation Cluster-role bindings](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/authentication/using-rbac.html#cluster-role-binding-commands_using-rbac):

```
$ oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user <role> <username>

Binds a given role to specified users for all projects in the cluster.
```

This meaning in same cluster boundaries.

and [stackoverflow previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45727200/how-to-allow-image-pull-from-one-project-to-another-in-openshift):

```
oc policy add-role-to-user \
    system:image-puller system:serviceaccount:testing2:default \
    --namespace=testing1

Your project testing2 will be able to access images from project testing1 in your openshift.
```

This meaning between projects (good) but in the same cluster (I need different cluster)

is there a way to set a role binding to be able to reach ImageStream from a different **cluster**? Or a cluster role? Or is it other way to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need a service account with `system:image-puller` role in the namespace you have your image stream then get the token from this service account and use this token as a `pull secret` from your other cluster.

I would recommend making a mirror ImageStream in your pulling cluster to manage the link.

[image: schema]

```
CLUSTER_TARGET=cluster-b
CLUSTER_PULLING=cluster-a
C_B_NAMESPACE=Y
C_B_SERVICEACCOUNT_FOR_PULL=${CLUSTER_PULLING}-sa
C_B_REGISTRY=image-registry.cluster-b.com:5000

IMAGE_ID=image:tag

# in oc command for Cluster B
oc create sa $C_B_SERVICEACCOUNT_FOR_PULL -n $C_B_NAMESPACE
oc policy add-role-to-user system:image-puller system:serviceaccount:$C_B_SERVICEACCOUNT_FOR_PULL -n $C_B_NAMESPACE
SA_TOKEN=$(oc sa get-token $C_B_SERVICEACCOUNT_FOR_PULL -n $C_B_NAMESPACE)

# in oc command for Cluster A
C_A_NAMESPACE=X
SECRET="{\"auths\":{\"$C_B_REGISTRY\":{\"auth\":\"$(base64 $SA_TOKEN)\",\"email\":\"you@example.com\"}}"
oc create secret generic ${CLUSTER_TARGET}-pullsecret \
    --from-literal=.dockerconfigjson=$SECRET \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson -n $C_A_NAMESPACE
oc secrets link default ${CLUSTER_TARGET}-pullsecret --for=pull -n $C_A_NAMESPACE
oc tag $C_B_REGISTRY/${C_B_NAMESPACE}/${IMAGE_ID} ${C_A_NAMESPACE}/${IMAGE_ID} --scheduled -n $C_A_NAMESPACE

# now you have a scheduled pull between A and B to your local ImageStream.
#If you want to use from another namespace in Cluster A:
oc create namespace Z
oc policy add-role-to-user system:image-puller system:serviceaccount:Z:default -n $C_A_NAMESPACE
echo "now pods in Z can reference image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc/${C_A_NAMESPACE}/${IMAGE_ID}"
```

[Checkout the pull secrets here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/openshift_images/managing_images/using-image-pull-secrets.html)
For Tekton, I'm not sure but basically you need:

- pull secret to pull from external repo
- service account with image-puller to pull locally (hense the local mirroring image stream to make your life easier)